# Using jQuery .animate() instead of .css()

Tags: javascript, jquery

So here is my app.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var cnt=0, bg;
var $body = $('body');
var arr = ['http://www.writerscentre.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Writing-Picture-Books-grid.jpg','bg2.jpg','bg3.jpg','bg4.jpg','bg5.jpg','bg6.jpg'];
var anim;
var bgrotater = setInterval(function() {
    if (cnt==5) cnt=0;
    bg = 'url("' + arr[cnt] + '")';
    cnt++;
    $body.css('background-image', bg);
   /* $body.animate({
        background-image = bg;
    },200)
    */

}, 1000);


 });
```

the $body.css works fine but can i get this to work with .animate()

Comment: And what do you expect animating the background image to do?

Comment: I wanted to make it fade in and out

Comment: @user, you would need to find (or write) a specific plugin to achieve that. Neither jQuery not jQuery UI support this feature out of the box.

Comment: Now im sad lol... Is their any other way to achieve this?

Comment: use ```$body.animate({opacity:0}, 'slow', function() {$(this).animate({opacity: 1})})```
  for fade effect

Comment: images aren't something you can gradually fade, try making a mock background with absolute positioning and fade the div's opacity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`animate` takes an object but you are defining the property like you define a variable.

Also due to the dash you need quotes around the property key.

`background-image = bg;`

Should be

`"background-image": bg`

The background image will not fade in and out though, it takes a lot more to do that, and animating `opacity` will fade in and out the element not the background.

There is a plugin that probably will help you do what you want see: [Vegas Background](http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/documentation/background/)